# how to perform filter based search with applying 2 filter simultaneously?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

i have search page where in there are 2 filters. one is the city and other is the service.
city values are  in usertable, where city is column , and service values are in an other service table 
when i search on applying  both the filters the output must display the answer merging both the result into one grid view /

please suggest logic  how can i do ?

Comment: What did you try so far?  Table structure and what SQL technology help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to join 2 tables together using an SQL query.

You can do what you ask in the same manner as below.

First let's imagine the structure of 2 tables, let's choose Human and Address as our tables.

Here's the Human table:

```
ID (PK AutoIncrement) | FirstName (nvarchar(50)) | LastName nvarchar(50)) | AddressID (int) |
1                     | Bob                      | Bobson                 | 8               |
2                     | Dob                      | Dobbers                | 9               |
```

Here's the Address table:

```
AddressID (PK AutoIncrement) | HouseNum (int)         | PostCode nvarchar(6)                        
8                            | 2                      | AL23FP                        
9                            | 37                     | AL23UR
```

You see that we can join these tables based on their `AddressID` as they share the values are mutual.

So you can query these 2 tables by doing something like this:

```
SELECT h.FirstName + ' ' + h.LastName AS Name, a.PostCode FROM HUMAN h
INNER JOIN Adress a on h.AddressID = a.AddressID
```

That's the basis for applying the query to your filters just with different table column names.

`INNER JOIN` will keep only the matching correspondance between the 2 tables if there's mutual info in both.

You can see other `Joins` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using stored procs in your SQL db, one way is to write a stored proc that takdse city and service as a parameter and returns the data using a SQL Join.  In your c# code or class, you can call the SQL stored proc and map it to a DataTable and parse the results and JSON serialize the data to send it back to the client.  If you are using Enitity Framework, you can do the same thing with Linq queries and map it to your c# model objects.  Then you can JSON serialize that data and send it back to the client.  On the client side code, you can parse the list and display it in your grid in whatever client framework you are using.

It would help to know more details about your server side and client side frameworks.